# Word Mail Merge: DISABLE alert message "Opening this will run the following SQL command" only for trusted files

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, windows-error-reporting, alert

I am using word for mail merge, but using this feature makes word prompt an alert message every time I open the document.
[image]

I understand that this alert is for security purposes, so **I would like to disable this alert only for the documents I know and trust. Is this possible?**

**If it is not possible to disable this alert for selected files, well, just get rid of it all together**

Comment: Check this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-receive-the-opening-this-will-run-the-following-sql-command-message-when-you-open-a-word-mail-merge-main-document-that-is-linked-to-a-data-source-aebb9d4b-003c-0d4b-2762-42ecdccbaced

Comment: That article will cancel the alert function altogether. instead of flagging some documents as trusted & safe =(

Answer (score 0):

For Office / Word 2021 there is no key in the Registry.

I added this key in the Registry and it worked without messages any longer.

HKEY_USERS\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options
add the key :  SQLSecurityCheck : DWORD = 0

And your warning message are gone!!!

I was inspired by the MS support page on Office 2010 and 2013 to give this a try.